# GARP packets not sent out for interfce up

Tags: linux, networking, ipv4, arp

I am working custom platform based on x86_64 running 3.10 kernel,
Recently I found an issue related to GARP. It seems like  no GARP
packets are being sent out when an Interface is made up. But I also
noticed that only when I use "arping" tool only then it sends out any
GARP packet.

I also try setting the net variable "arp_notify" then I see the
arp_send() function is being called after that I am unable to track
further.

Could you please help me, what could be issue, Is it a valid
expectation that during interface up the linux kernel should send out
GARP packet? If so, am I missing any kernel configuration related to
it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a document misleading?